# How to migrate Identity Server 6 Code Configuration into Database?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver6

I'm using Identity Server 6 and have followed various quickstarts to get started with this. I have a coded configuration (in my Config.cs file) but my IS server is now using the EF Database configuration provider for MS SQL.
I now want to take my coded client configuration and migrate it in to my database. I found an article which outlines one approach to writing code that will do this. The code is shown below.
However, this code won't compile in my IS 6 project, because the **InMemoryConfig** object is not recognised. I'm speculating that this is because the code was perhaps built for an earlier version of IS; however since I am not familiar with the IS source code, I don't know where to even begin when it comes to updating or adapting this.

Basically, any solution which will automate the process of getting the IS 6 code configuration written in to the IS 6 EF database, is what I'm looking for.

Would very much appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```
using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.DbContexts;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class MigrationManager
    {
        public static IHost MigrateDatabase(this IHost host)
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

                using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        context.Database.Migrate();

                        if (!context.Clients.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var client in InMemoryConfig.GetClients())
                            {
                                context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                            }
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var resource in InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                            {
                                context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                            }
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        if (!context.ApiScopes.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var apiScope in InMemoryConfig.GetApiScopes())
                            {
                                context.ApiScopes.Add(apiScope.ToEntity());
                            }

                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        if (!context.ApiResources.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var resource in InMemoryConfig.GetApiResources())
                            {
                                context.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                            }
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Log errors or do anything you think it's needed
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }

            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moved to auth0 instead.